# MS Test agent threads not picking up system culture

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, cultureinfo, currentculture

It seems that the agent threads spawned by MS Test when running the tests do not have their current culture set to the current system culture.

More specifically, the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` property always returns the "en-US" culture, even if i set my Windows culture to a different one, such as German or French.

This only seems to happen when running the tests, because if i run that code normally, the culture is set to the correct one.

Is this an actual feature of MS Test? As far as i know all threads in .NET have by default the current system culture associated to them, is MS Test somehow always forcing it to "en-US"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the culprit, it's not MS Test, it's Specflow - there's a [known issue](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/265) reported some time ago but still not fixed. My tests were using Specflow, which in turn uses MS Test.